# How to declare multiple instances for the same type?

Tags: haskell

I have the following instance:

```
instance Show ZZ where
   show zz = toHexa (zzToInt zz)
```

I need another instance of `Show` for the type `ZZ` like

```
instance Show ZZ where
   show zz = ...
```

How can I solve this problem? I need to declare the second `Show` in another way.

Comment: I doubt your business or classroom goal was stated as "you need as second show instance of this Haskell type."  What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 7):

You can only have one instance per type. If you need (or rather, want) another one, you need to define a new type.

```
newtype ZZOther = ZZOther ZZ

instance Show ZZOther where
    show (ZZOther zz) = ... -- do something with zz :: ZZ
```

Comment: It's worth discussing https://doi.org/10.1145/3242744.3242752 in this context.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, I'm really not a big fan of their approach. The coherence mechanism is complex and smells brittle. Have you seen my GHC proposal for local types and locally defined instances? It's much narrower, but seems likely better behaved.

Comment: Is there a link to a freely available copy of the paper?